# how to access activex from firefox

Tags: firefox, plugins, activex

i had developed an activex control to communicate web browser with the local machine . it is working fine for me with Internet Explorer . how can i communicate my activex in firefox and chrome.

will you please anyone say me how to develop plugins to communicate with .net ActiveX control

Comment: Why would one want to do that? Developing for ActiveX means one targets only one single type of system: MS-Windows. So if one actively decides to support only a monopol, then why bother about alternative browsers? Does not make sense in my eyes...

Comment: hi Arkascha , thanks for your comments. but our clients prefers to use firefox that is main problem for me here

Comment: Sure, but then you clearly chose the wrong technology. ActiveX is a major tool for MS to increase its monopoly. It is closed, no alternatives, no other players allowed here, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveX will work only in IE 
All other browsers use different plugins API (NPAPI)
So you have to implement separate plugin for this browsers

Answer (score 0):

Build your plugin in [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org) instead of in ActiveX; FireBreath plugins build as both activex controls and npapi plugins and work on all browsers.